# Can't install external packages in Python

Tags: python-2.7

My problem is when I'm trying to install an external package via **Command Prompt**, I'm getting an error. I've just started programming and I don't understand everything yet.

That's an error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't include your stack trace as an image, because it makes it significantly harder for others to search for your question *and* it is more inconvenient to view. Paste it in to the text box, then highlight and press Ctrl+K to indent and get [code block formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Also, do you happen to have Python 3 installed on the system as well?

Comment: Yes, I have Python 3 installed also

Comment: Try `python2.7 -m easy_install twilio`.

Comment: It helped, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll post this as an answer so you can mark your problem as solved, unless you have any objections.

Comment: Everything's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Python 2 and Python 3 are both installed on the system, they can interfere and cause `easy_install` to break.

Hence, you will need to specify which version of Python and `easy_install` you want, like this:

```
python-2.7 -m easy_install <module>
```

For any other version of Python, just change the `-2.7` to your `major.minor` version.